# Warning: system call failed: Cannot allocate memory while installing ‘shiny’ on R 3.1.2

Tags: r, shiny

Hello I was trying to use shiny package with R 3.1.2. But it seems that the package has not been update to cater to this new R version.

Does Anybody has suggestions? I was thinking about downgrade my R back to 3.1.1. I don't know if there's any better ideas than this one....

Comment: How exactly did you try to install it? Older versions of packages should work with newer version of R. Perhaps try selecting an alternate CRAN mirror for installation.

Comment: Hi MrFlick. Thanks for suggestion. I find my issue was not that. I had a warning saying:system call failed: Cannot allocate memory Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is clearly something wrong at your end as many of us have shiny on current R installations:

```
R> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)"
R> packageDescription("shiny")[1:4]
$Package
[1] "shiny"

$Type
[1] "Package"

$Title
[1] "Web Application Framework for R"

$Version
[1] "0.11"

R>
```

But from the information you have provided we cannot deduce why you seem to be unable to install this (current) version of shiny in your current R version.

Comment: Hi Dirk: Thank you for the info. You're right. It's not the version problem. I had following warnings:Warning in install.packages :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Good to know.  In which case it is common to _upvote_ (click on arrow-up) and/or _accept_ (click on tick-mark).

Comment: Just click ACCEPT your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to install Shiny on a Ubuntu server and the error is simply because server is out of memory. Please make sure you have enough memory before installing.